# Updating date in fields in project

Tags: vba, runtime-error, ms-project, datefield

I have the following problem updating MS Project fields with VBA:

I try this:

```
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks 

     'The following displays correctly Mo 14.05.18
     Debug.Print Format(CDate("14.05.18", " ddd dd.mm.yy"))

     'The following results in an error 438 (Method not supported)
     t.Datum3 = Format(CDate("12.05.18","ddd dd.mm.yy"))
    'this works fine but i'm not able to sort it proberly since it is a text sort for date fields, which is not wanted ...
    't.Text25 = Format(CDate("12.05.15","ddd dd.mm.yy"))
 Next t
```

It seems that not the format is a problem (I tried various formats, I even read it from the object to verify with format should be used) but generally, I'm not able to update date fields, I've got these problems with predefined  date fields from MS Project as well as with user defined date fields.

Text fields don't make any problems at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Be sure to check out the [tour], as well as [ask].  If you're having an issue with something _specific_, please [edit] your questions to provide more information (such as sample data and which error(s) you're having (and where they are occurring) and examples (like described in here: [mcve]) and share what you've tried & where you've looked so far.  This site will help to [get you started with VBA](http://www.homeandlearn.org/).

Comment: Be sure to post your code accurately. Your issue is a **run-time error**, but the code posted has a **compile error** (missing a closing parentheses). Other than that, this is a well-formed question--it contains all the information necessary for an MS Project VBA question (disregard the downvote you received).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method**

You are getting the run-time error 438  because the `Task` object does not have a property called `Datum3`. Even though the field title in the German version is "Datum3", the actual property name is `Date3`. ([see MS Project object model, German version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/project-vba/articles/task-date3-property-project))

**Secondary issue**

While MS Project will accept date field values formatted as text, it is not necessary and bad form as it implies the date field is text. Instead set the values like this:

```
t.Date3 = CDate("14.05.18")
```

Note: The display format for date fields is set in the Project Options (see [Change the Date Format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-date-format-3c92bc51-6fd4-4c2c-aae7-0dde6cae4358) or [Ändern des Datumsformats](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/%C3%84ndern-des-datumsformats-3c92bc51-6fd4-4c2c-aae7-0dde6cae4358)).

Comment: That works fine, you're absolutely right, thx a lot! There was a confusion about english and german!

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Rachel's answer is best... but, another approach if your core need is to sort and you are stuck with text, is to use dates in ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DD . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 for details. Or better yet: https://xkcd.com/1179/ .